# ehCache нет записи в файл

Tags: java, java-ee, кэширование, spring-boot

При кешировании БД методом не происходит запись данных файл, хотя как я понимаю должно. Подскажите в чем причина

Конфигурационный файл

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
        updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
        <diskStore path="D:\"/>
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="10000"
            eternal="false"
            timeToIdleSeconds="100"
            timeToLiveSeconds="180"
            overflowToDisk="true"
            maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
            diskPersistent="true"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
    <cache name="contacts"
           maxElementsInMemory="10000000"
           eternal="false"
           clearOnFlush="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="10"
           timeToIdleSeconds="100"
           timeToLiveSeconds="180"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Сервис

```
    @Override
    public List<Contact> regExFilterContacts(String filter) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filter);
        Matcher matcher;
        List<Contact> allContacts = getAllContacts();
        if (filter.equals("") || filter.equals(null)) {
            return allContacts;
        }
        logger.info("Start filtering...");
        List<Contact> filterListContact = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        for (Contact oneContact : allContacts) {
            matcher = pattern.matcher(oneContact.getName());
            if (!matcher.find()) {
                filterListContact.add(oneContact);
            }
        }
        return filterListContact;
    }

}
```

Контроллер

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/contacts", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Contact>> getContacts(@RequestParam(value = "nameFilter", defaultValue = "") String name) {
        log.info("Filter String is " + name);
        List<Contact> filterContacts = contactService.regExFilterContacts(name);
        Integer filterContactSize = filterContacts.size();
        if (filterContactSize.equals(0)) {
            log.info("For you query contacts not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Contact>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Contact>>(filterContacts, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

заранее благодарен

Comment: а где вы пытаетесь записать в файл? ничего не вижу

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян как я понимаю при вызове метода getAllContacts идёт запись на файл. Вызов происходит в контроллере который я добавил.

Comment: На сколько понимаю, чтобы пошла запись в файл, нужно сначала добавить maxElementsInMemory + 1 элементов в кэш

Comment: @Russtam не совсем понял о чём вы.

Comment: Вы сказали что ehCache не пишет данные в файл, и привели конфиг (сейчас он куда-то пропал). Я вам и ответил, что ehCache будет скидывать в файл данные, только когда элементов в кэше будет maxElementsInMemory + 1. Или уточните вопрос.

Comment: @Russtam попробовал ваш способ. Проблему не решает